# What counts as a comparison?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

Say we have a test in which we are comparing many variables to a dependent variable, using different methods. Say ttest, chi2 and then finally a multiple regression on parts of the data.

Would we include every single ttest, chi2 and every variable in the multiple regression when doing our bonferroni correction?

What if we have 3 dependent variables that we are investigating in the same study. Would we could everything in the same way over the course of the 3 variables, or would each dependent variable be counted as one "unit"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You perform a Bonferoni correction to avoid an inflation of the Type 1 error rate (rejecting the Nullhypothesis although it is true). The Chance of making a Type 1 Error when you do a single test for example a t-test is your alpha level, usually 0.05.

However, when you perform a second test then the chance that you get at least one Type 1 Error increases to almost 10% instead of the 5% that you had when you only did one test.
In order to avoid this inflation we use the above mentioned Correction.

Technically, for each p-value that you/the computer calculates you need to correct for. But most researchers do not do that. In fact, staying true to the definition, you would need to correct for any test for which you calculated a p-value across your whole life.

As you can see that is almost impossible and here is also where the whole concept of p-values kind of breaks apart.

In a more practical way, correcting your p-value is something that researchers do not really agree on. SOme only do it for post-hoc tests of ANOVAS. People, with a more thorough understanding usually correct for more test. But it all depends on the situation, your supervisors and how strict you feel about Type 1 inflation.

The best idea is too just try avoiding todo multiple tests. 
For example you can use a MANOVA for your three dependent variables, instead of testing them separately ( If they are related). Also if you have to correct do not use the Bonforroni Corrections ( it has a low power) I recommend the Benjamini-Hochberg correction.

Comment: So perhaps correcting for p-values is important if doing research that pertains to a clinical decision, but for more exploratory articles, correcting for them is not as important?

Comment: The blanket assertion "when you perform a second test then the chance that you get at least one Type 1 Error increases to almost 10%" is not generally correct because it assumes the tests are statistically independent.  The "every single test" situation posited in this question strongly suggests this is not the case. The statement ending "across your whole life" is a gross exaggeration, too, because the relevance of multiple testing is to the set of decisions ensuing from one particular study, not during one's entire career.

Comment: But in which situation would the tests not be independent of each other. And while of course my statement with correcting your Type1 error rate over your whole career is an exaggeration, its not wrong. The more test you do, the higher the chance that you make a Type 1 error and that does not magically reset when you start a new study. You could also ask that two researchers working on two studies with the same dataset should also include the number of tests of other researcher to correct for. I am not saying that its good practice, but just by the definition of a p-value

Comment: The tests will be interdependent in most situations.  For instance, if you are testing a hypothesis about a variance (which is what one kind of chi-squared test does) with the same data you are testing a hypothesis about a mean using the same data, the tests very well could be interdependent.  Some people compare means as well as compare medians with the same data: that would be two strongly dependent results. As far as the "whole career" issue goes, it's both irrelevant and misleading because it misconstrues the entire purpose of hypothesis testing as well as missing the point of corrections.

Comment: Well it might misconstruct how the corrections are used in actual research. But as I if you stick to the true definition of a Null Hypothesis Significance Test and the p-value. You would need to correct for all tests you will do in your career. Of course nobody can know how many tests he will do in a career and it is not feasible. But the fact is a researcher who did 1000 significance test is likely to have made more Type 1 erros than a researcher who only did 20. Independent of how they spread them across different studies